# "Compile error: Expected: list separator or )"

Tags: vba, worksheet-function

I have the following code in my VBA module

```
For i = 4 To lastOutputCol
  If Sheets("Mort Rates").Cells(1, i).Value Mod 5 = 0 Then
    For x = 2 To lastOutputRow
      Sheets("Mort Rates").Cells(x, i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index( _
       Sheets("Input").Range(Cells(17,dbPerkCol),Cells(lastInputRow,dbPerkCol+2)) _
      ,Application.WorksheetFunction.Match( Sheets("Mort Rates").Cells(x,2)& _
       Sheets("Mort Rates").Cells(1,i)&Sheets("Mort Rates").Cells(x,3) _
      ,Sheets("Input).Range(Cells(17,1),Cells(lastInputRow,1)),0),1)
    Next x
  End If
Next i
```

And I am getting this error:

> Compile error:
>
> Expected: list separator or )

I'm not sure why.

Comment: Missing double quote on `Sheets("Input")`?

Comment: If you decide to add `With Sheets("Mort Rates")` you can "clean" up your code quite a bit